# Go Error: continue is not in a loop

Tags: go

I have written go code which has a for loop, code is given below. but when i build the code i get 'continue is not within loop'. i can't understand why this is happening. Kindly help

Go Version:

> go version go1.7.5 linux/amd64

Complete Code at the below link
https://pastebin.com/0ZypMYVK

reference Screenshot
[image]

```
for k:=0;k < len(args);k++{
    fmt.Println("k is ", k)
    hsCode := args[k]
    lenChk:=checkHashLen(hsCode)
    if lenChk==false {
        fmt.Println("Length should be 32" )
        continue
    }
    codeBytes,_ := json.Marshal(hsCode)

    APIstub.PutState(strconv.FormatInt(makeTimestamp(),10), codeBytes)
    fmt.Println("Added: ", k)     
}
```

Error[image]

> ./hashcode.go:88: continue is not in a loop

Comment: It is unlikely. How much did you change your code before posting here?

Comment: Please, post [mcve].

Comment: The code posted does not trigger the posted error.

Comment: I have added the link for the complete code for reference

Comment: update screen shots for validity

Comment: https://pastebin.com/0ZypMYVK -> line 85 - continue outside loop is here.

Comment: Now it's line 88 in the question, 87 on the screenshot and 85 in the code you provided. Being careful, is very important when you code. 99% of mistakes you'll be making next months (years?) will be due to lack of attention.

Comment: That line difference is there becoz i had to copy the code function by function to the paste bin from my vm, due to some issues. code is same everywhere line difference is because of paste.

Comment: Do not post screen shots of text. Copy and paste the text instead.

Comment: @Flimzy   I have posted both.. screen shot i pasted as i was asked if i posted the same code here as the one i executed.

Comment: Your screen shot and code don't match.

Comment: @Flimzy i dont see difference in both... but in case u see any difference. u can consider the complete code, that i have provided in the pastebin link

Comment: If you don't see a difference, it's because you're not looking. Your screen shot contains many lines not contained in the text.  If those lines aren't important, then just remove the screen shot. If they are important, then put them in the text--and then remove the screen shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
//push single code on the block
func (s *SmartContract) pushCode(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) sc.Response {

    hsCode := args[0]
    lenChk := checkHashLen(hsCode)
    if lenChk == false {
        fmt.Println("Length should be 32")
        continue
    }
    codeBytes, _ := json.Marshal(hsCode)
    APIstub.PutState(strconv.FormatInt(makeTimestamp(), 10), codeBytes)
    return shim.Success(nil)
}
```

The error explains what is going wrong. You're using the keyword continue when not in a for loop, this function doesn't contain a for loop.

initCodeLedger contains a for loop, so you are getting distracted by that, but that's not the line no given in the error which is around line 86/87/88. Ideally post code on play.golang.org if asking a question like this.

Comment: Thats a big stupidity on my part.. should i delete this question?

Comment: Don't worry, we all do it, next time try to give a reproduction others can try, as it helps pin it down. The piling on to downvote the question is unfortunate, I'm not sure why that's become a habit around here.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep suggestions in mind when posting next time.